# What is this small field with two oval lanes?

Tags: match-identification

I am wondering what sport/activity is played on this field.

It's located between a skatepark and other sport fields, there was no signs.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Is there any reason to believe this is anything other than a small running track, possibly for juniors?

Comment: Could you provide a location for this aerial image?